# WSO2APIM is case sensitive

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I had a problem with api manager, the context that I created it's all in lower case, but some clients send request the context with capital letters, and api manager don't recognize these calls, but in the publiser interface is case insensitive, the context **application.api** is the same **Application.Api**, there some way to fix this, create some sequence to fix requests or api manager follow the the RFC 2616 section 3.2.3, where clients needs to request uri in case sensitive?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As stated in the HTTP/1.1 specification, RFC2621 section 3.2.3 [1] the path in HTTP URLs are required to be case-sensitive.

[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.3